# Duplicate web form on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, updatepanel

I have an ASP web form that includes divs, checkboxes, textboxes, buttons and dropdowns. Backend is c#.

I have an "Add" button at the bottom that when clicked, I want it to duplicate my form below the existing one.

Other than copying my form multiple times and toggling visibility based on a button click, is there some way I can put my form in a class and call on it based on the button click? Or any other way? Would think `gridview` is an option but I use divs within the form which is not allowed in `gridview`.

For Example:

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />           
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnl" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" Text="Add" />
            </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </form>
```

The Add button can be moved outside of the update panel if necessary. But I would like to duplicate the form below the original via clicking the Add button. Would also be handy if I could have a remove option as well.

Comment: To do something like this in ASP.net you need to create user control (ASCX) and work with that, not the form (ASPX). Although, you need both. The form will be your container where you going to duplicate your user control. What "toggling"?? - you in the WEB...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! By toggling, I mean changing the visibility back and forth from true/false. I haven't dabbled into user controls so I'll do some research on it. Thx.